# Как изменить цену товара при оформлении заказа WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Каким образом я могу изменить цену товара при оформлении заказа в корзине?

На данный момент реализован расчет необходимой цены из условий доставки, после получения результатов расчета меняю цену простым изменением переменной price у товара. Это дает результат при проверке цены на стадии оформления, но после нажатия на кнопку "Оформить заказ" на странице с информацией о заказе (да и в самом заказе) цена у товара остается прежней, как и до перерасчета, то есть подтягивается явно из карточки товара, но никак не из корзины.

Есть ли какой-либо способ эту цену в заказ передавать из корзины или подскажите, какой именно хук мне подправить, чтобы подставлялась в заказ нужная мне цена?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте хук добавления товара в корзину:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'my_add_cart_item', 10, 1 );
function my_add_cart_item($cart_item) {
    $cart_item['data']->set_price('1000');
}
```